# How to properly declare hash outside BEGIN block?

Tags: perl

Consider this simple program. Can you explain why the output is different after uncommenting the first two lines? What is happening with my hash with `use strict`? How to fix the program to work with `use strict`?

```
echo -e "key1\nkey2\nkey3" | perl -lne '
  #use strict; use warnings;
  #my %hash;
  BEGIN { 
    $hash{'key3'} = "value";
  }   
  chomp;
  if ($hash{$_}) {
    print "$_ matched";
  } else {
    print "$_ unmatched ";
  }
'
```

Output:

```
key1 unmatched 
key2 unmatched 
key3 matched
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `-n` switch implictly puts your entire program inside a `while (defined($_=<ARGV>)) { ...` block, including your `my %hash` statement:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -lne '
  use strict; use warnings; my %hash;
  BEGIN {
    $hash{'key3'} = "value";
  }
  chomp;
  if ($hash{$_}) {
    print "$_ matched";
  } else {
    print "$_ unmatched ";
  }
'

BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    use warnings;
    use strict 'refs';
    my %hash;
    sub BEGIN {
        $hash{'key3'} = 'value';
    }
    &BEGIN;
    chomp $_;
    if ($hash{$_}) {
        print "$_ matched";
    }
    else {
        print "$_ unmatched ";
    }
}
-e syntax OK
```

That is, `my %hash` is redeclared in each iteration of the loop. To keep this as a one-liner and without making it too cumbersome, consider declaring `our %hash` to make `%hash` a package variable.

Comment: Accepted answer for the Deparse trick. I wouldn't have needed to ask  the question if I had known about that.

Answer (score 5):

`perl -ln` wraps the code so that you end up with

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (<>) {
    chomp;
    use strict; use warnings;
    my %hash;
    BEGIN { $hash{key3} = "value"; }
    ...
}
```

Notice how you create a new `%hash` for every line? If you wanted to use `use strict;`, you'd use a package variable.

```
perl -lne'
    use strict; use warnings;
    our %hash;
    BEGIN { $hash{key3} = "value"; }
    ...
'
```

Otherwise, you have to drop `-n`.

```
perl -le'
    use strict; use warnings;
    my %hash = ( key3 => "value" );
    while (<>) {
        chomp;
        ...
    }
'
```

PS - As you may have noticed, it's useless to `chomp` when using both `-l` and `-n`.