# PERL to count non-printable characters

Tags: perl, ascii, non-ascii-characters, non-printable

I have 100,000's of files that I would like to analyze.  Specifically I would like to calculate the percentage of printable characters from a sample of the file of arbitrary size.  Some of these files are from mainframes, Windows, Unix, etc. so it is likely that binary and control characters are included.

I started by using the Linux "file" command, but it did not provide enough detail for my purposes.  The following code conveys what I am trying to do, but does not always work.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -n

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $cnt_n_print = 0;
    my $cnt_print = 0;
    my $cnt_total = 0;
    my $prc_print = 0;

    #Count the number of non-printable characters
    while ($_ =~ m/[^[:print:]]/g) {$cnt_n_print++};

    #Count the number of printable characters
    while ($_ =~ m/[[:print:]]/g) {$cnt_print++};

    $cnt_total = $cnt_n_print + $cnt_print;
    $prc_print = $cnt_print/$cnt_total;

    #Print the # total number of bytes read followed by the % printable
    print "$cnt_total|$prc_print\n"
```

This is a test call that works:

```
    echo "test_string of characters" | /home/user/scripts/prl/s16_count_chars.pl
```

This is how I intend to call it, and works for one file:

```
    find /fct/inbound/trans/ -name "TRNST.20121115231358.xf2" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 head -c 2000 | /home/user/scripts/prl/s16_count_chars.pl
```

This does not work correctly:

```
    find /fct/inbound/trans/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 head -c 2000 | /home/user/scripts/prl/s16_count_chars.pl
```

Neither does this:

```
    find /fct/inbound/trans/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 head -c 2000 | perl -0 /home/user/scripts/prl/s16_count_chars.pl
```

Instead of executing the script once for EACH line returned by the find, it executes ONCE for ALL the results.

Thanks in advance.

---

Research so far:

Pipe and XARGS and separators

http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/help-understand-pipe-xargs--ftopict549399.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem

---

***Clarification(s):***
1.) Desired output: If there are 932 files in a directory, the output would be a 932 line list of file names, the total bytes read from the file and the % that were printable characters.
2.) Many of the files are binary.  Script needs to handle embedded binary `eol` or `eof` sequences.
3.) Many of the files are large, so I would like to only read the first/last xx bytes.  I had been trying to use `head -c 256` or `tail -c 128` to read either the first 256 bytes or the last 128 bytes respectively. Solution could either work in a pipe line or limit bytes within perl script.

Comment: `while ($_ =~ m/[^[:print:]]/g) {$cnt_n_print++};` is better done as `$cnt_n_print += ( () = m/[^[:print:]]/g );`  (or better yet, using tr///, only that doesn't support POSIX classes)

Comment: "Better" = faster, more concisely, but uses more memory. Possibly quite a lot more, actually. (A whole string scalar per matching character!)

Comment: Noooo! Not `-n` on the shebang line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my **working solution** based on the feedback provided.

I would appreciate any further feedback on form or more efficient methods:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    # This program receives a file path and name.
    # The program attempts to read the first 2000 bytes.
    # The output is a list of files, the number of bytes
    # actually read and the percent of tbe bytes that are
    # ASCII "printable" aka [\x20-\x7E].

    my ($data, $n_bytes, $file_name, $cnt_n_print, $cnt_print, $prc_print);

    # loop through each file
    foreach(@ARGV) {
       $file_name = shift or die "Pass the file name on the command line.\n";

       # open the file read only with "<" in "<$file_name"
       open(FILE, "<$file_name") or die "Can't open $file_name: $!";

       # open each file in binary mode to handle non-printable characters
       binmode FILE;

       # try to read 2000 bytes from FILE, save the results in $data and the
       # actual number of bytes read in $n_bytes
       $n_bytes = read FILE, $data, 2000;

       $cnt_n_print = 0;
       $cnt_print = 0;

       # count the number of non-printable characters
       ++$cnt_n_print while ($data =~ m/[^[:print:]]/g);

       $cnt_print = $n_bytes - $cnt_n_print;
       $prc_print = $cnt_print/$n_bytes;

       print "$file_name|$n_bytes|$prc_print\n";
       close(FILE);
    }
```

Here is a sample of how to call the above script:

```
    find /some/path/to/files/ -type f -exec perl this_script.pl {} +
```

---

Here's a list of references I found helpful:

[POSIX Bracket Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)
[Opening files in binmode](http://oreilly.com/catalog/cookbook/chapter/ch08.html)
[Read function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html)
[Open file read only](http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlfileopen.php)

Comment: @mob @ikegami In further testing, I am finding that this solution skips some of the files in a directory if called using the above listed `find` command.  For example, in one directory there are 39 files, but the script only outputs information on 20.  If I run the script on each of the files individually, it also works without error for the 19 skipped by using `find`.  Do you have any ideas on how to have the script run for all the files in a directory?

Comment: @mob @ikegami @ysth  If I call the Perl script from a batch script, it runs for all the files: `find /some/path/to/files/ -type f -print|while read filename
   do
      perl /path/to/this_script.pl $filename
   done`   What is the "RIGHT" way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

The `-n` option wraps your entire code in a `while(defined($_=<ARGV>) { ... }` block. This means your `my $cnt_print` and other variable declarations are repeated for every line of input, essentially resetting all your variable values.

The workaround is to use global variables (declare them with `our` if you want to keep using `use strict`), and not to initialize them to `0`, as they would be reinitialized for every line of input. You could say something like

```
our $cnt_print //= 0;
```

if you don't want `$cnt_print` and its friends to be undefined for the first line of input.

See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130119/168657) with a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...As for the "-n" option, the implied while loop is what I want.  If I pass the script 172 files, I want 172 distinct outputs (one for each file).  Is there a best practice to use either "-n" or an explicit "while"?

Answer (score 1):

You could have `find` pass you one arg at a time.

```
find /fct/inbound/trans/ -type f -exec perl script.pl {} \;
```

But I'd continue passing multiple files at a time, either through `xargs`, or using GNU `find`'s `-exec +`.

```
find /fct/inbound/trans/ -type f -exec perl script.pl {} +
```

The following code snippets support both.

You can continue reading a line at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $cnt_total   = 0;
my $cnt_n_print = 0;

while (<>) {
    $cnt_total += length;
    ++$cnt_n_print while /[^[:print:]]/g;
} continue {
    if (eof) {
        my $cnt_print = $cnt_total - $cnt_n_print;
        my $prc_print = $cnt_print/$cnt_total;

        print "$ARGV: $cnt_total|$prc_print\n";

        $cnt_total   = 0;
        $cnt_n_print = 0;
    }
}
```

Or you could read a whole file at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
while (<>) {
    my $cnt_n_print = 0;
    ++$cnt_n_print while /[^[:print:]]/g;

    my $cnt_total = length;
    my $cnt_print = $cnt_total - $cnt_n_print;
    my $prc_print = $cnt_print/$cnt_total;

    print "$ARGV: $cnt_total|$prc_print\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  REALLY close, but I think it chokes on binary files, and I need to read only the first X bytes (see clarification above).  Also I could only get the GNU -exec to work.  Can you help update the script so that it can either work in a linux pipeline with the head/tail command like:
a) find /fct/inbound/trans/ -name "TRNST.20121115231358.xf2" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 head -c 2000 | /home/user/scripts/prl/s16_count_chars.pl

or something like:
b) find /path/to/analyze/ -type f -exec perl script.pl {} first 264 +
c) find /path/to/analyze/ -type f -exec perl script.pl {} last 128 +

Comment: Well, `readline` (`<>`) is not very appropriate for binary files. You'd want `read` instead. Iterate over the files using `for 
(@ARGV)` and open them yourself.

Comment: Could you include an example that works with the output from a find command?  I found this reference but still having problems [Perl File Handling: open, read, write and close files](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/perlfile.shtml)

Comment: Sorry, can't help with problems you mention nothing about.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I posted my working solution based on your recommendations.